# IntelliJ IDEA - can I have automatically incremented build (version) number?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, version

Can I set somehow IntelliJ building process to pre-process Java source codes and give me ever incrementing build number? Something like:

```
int myBuildNumber = INTELLI_J_IDEA_MAGIC_WHICH_WILL_INCREMENT_EVERY_BUILD;
```

Comment: Interesting question. What problem does its solution solve?

Comment: I cannot think of a simple, intelliJ only solution, but what about using ``ant`` to do that? You could trigger an ant task from within intelliJ directly. This way the process could be IDE-agnostic.

Comment: Petur: Well not much - only I can ask colleagues what version of my tool they use and I can tell them if it's the last one. Even if I forget to change the version manually before I give it away... The next step would be to link it with revision system number somehow. But I wanted for now just something quick and dirty and fancy looking number like 125 :)

Comment: @AtomHeartFather: is there some simple example of exactly that? I do not want to spend a day to learn new build environment only for incrementing build number...

Comment: @VitBernatik There is an ``ant`` task specifically for that purpose. Have a look at https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/buildnumber.html

Comment: @VitBernatik any luck with that? Too be honest I have never used this particular task, but did something similar manually in the past. Hopefully with this task it should all go smoothly. Once you have your build number in the property file, you should be able to load it just like any other property. Hope that helps.

Comment: So it worked :) although it took me like an 1.5 hour to find what is what and where...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok so with hint from AtomHeartFather I got it.

First we need to write an ant xml file. This file will create file where build number will be stored and incremented and then it will look through your source code file `${src}/com/yourPath/Main.java` 
for variable `public static final String BUILD_NUMBER = ".*";` and replace it with current build number

The xml file would look like this:

```
<project name="MyProject" default="init" basedir=".">
    <description>
        simple example increment build variable
    </description>
  <!-- set global properties for this build -->
  <property name="src" location="../src"/>

  <target name="init">
    <echo file="myAntOut.txt">My first ant ${src} ${line.separator}</echo>

    <buildnumber/>
    <replaceregexp file="${src}/com/yourPath/Main.java"
               match="public\s+static\s+final\s+String\s+BUILD_NUMBER\s+=\s+&quot;.*&quot;;"
               replace="public static final String BUILD_NUMBER = &quot;${build.number}&quot;;"
               byline="true"
    />

  </target>
</project>
```

Then in your intelliJ (I'm using 14.0.3) you click on `View->Tool Windows->Ant Build`. Then `+` and browse to your xml file (note that current path used by your xml will be the path to that xml file itself - not inteliJ project - thus you may want to correct the part `location="../src"` depending on where you store your xml). Than you shall see our target `init` you can select it and click `play` button. If it works you shall see `BUILD_NUMBER` incremented in you source code file `Main.java`. Now the important trick how to make it automatically: Just right click on `init` and select `Execute on->Before Compilation`. Done :)

Comment: This is really a great answer. Kudos to you.

Comment: Tipp: You can also execute the Ant-file when the (release) packages are built. Just follow these steps (assuming you've already an Artifact): Build -> edit Artifact -> (Tab) Pre-processing -> Run Ant target "init" :)

Comment: Awesome answer Vit, saved lot of irritation for me. How to generate build number strings custom like 1.1.1 etc?